# How to add a custom field depends on back order option in product edit page(under advance inventory) in magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, product-edit-page

How to add a  custom field depends on  back order option in product edit page(under advance inventory) in magento 2 admin

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <modal name="advanced_inventory_modal">
        <fieldset name="stock_data">
            <container name="container_backorders">
                <field name="backorders" formElement="select" component="SR_MagentoCommunity/js/backorders"/>
                <field name="custom_input" formElement="input">
                    <settings>
                        <scopeLabel>[GLOBAL]</scopeLabel>
                        <label translate="true">Custom Input</label>
                        <dataScope>custom_input</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                </field>
            </container>
        </fieldset>
    </modal>
</form>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/web/js/backorders.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select'
], function (_, uiRegistry, select) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({

        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var customInput = uiRegistry.get('index = custom_input');
            if (this.value() == 1) {
                customInput.show();
            } else {
                customInput.hide();
            }
            return this;
        },
        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            var customInput = uiRegistry.get('index = custom_input');
            if (value == 1) {
                customInput.show();
            } else {
                customInput.hide();
            }
            return this._super();
        }
    });
});
```

*Now this new field will visible if you select **Allow Qty Below 0** from backorder dropdown.*

[Update]

You need to change xml for M2.1

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <modal name="advanced_inventory_modal">
        <fieldset name="stock_data">
            <container name="container_backorders">
                <field name="backorders">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_MagentoCommunity/js/backorders</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
            </container>
                <field name="custom_input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Input</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_input</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
        </fieldset>
    </modal>
</form>
```

Comment: It shows Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Element 'field', attribute 'formElement': The attribute 'formElement' is not allowed.

Comment: Is your magento version > M2.3? I tested with M2.3

Comment: my magento version is 2.1.3

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: i will check and update you

Comment: its work like a charm

Comment: can you please help me to solve [this issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273861/how-to-save-advance-inventory-custom-field-value-in-db-in-magento-2/)

Comment: Using the above code, I created the custom field and saved the values inventory table, i need to populate the saved value on top of the field, can any one share your idea and input