# How to save advance inventory custom field value in db in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, inventory, custom-field

How to save **advance inventory custom field value** in DB on Magento 2

[image]

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after">
    <observer name="Vendor_Module::save_custom_data" 
         instance="Cm\Preorder\Observer\AfterProductSave"/>
  </event>
</config>
```

AfterProductSave.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\Preorder\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class AfterProductSave implements ObserverInterface
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
}
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)

 {
$post = $this->_request->getPost();
var_dump($post);
 }

}
```

**Updated**

> Cm/Preorder/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="preorder_button" instance="Cm\Preorder\Observer\AfterProductSave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Cm\Preorder\Observer\AfterProductSave.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\Preorder\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class AfterProductSave implements ObserverInterface
{ 
     protected $_scopeConfig;
     protected $_request;
     protected $_objectManager;


     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager


    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_request = $request;

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

         $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object 
        $product_id = $_product->getId();
        $preorder_button=$_product->getPreorderButton(); 
        $preorder_note=$_product->getPreorderNote();

        $display_text= $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('preorder/display/btn_text');
         $display_note= $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('preorder/display/pre_order_note');


            $preorder_button = $display_text;        


            $preorder_note = $display_note;

        $resource = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` WHERE  `product_id`=$product_id";
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
         $res = $connection->fetchAll($query);
        if($res)
            {
               $var = array_column($res, 'product_id');
                $key = key($var);
                $id = $var[$key];
                $sql = "UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET preorder_button = '$preorder_button' , preorder_note ='$preorder_note' , website_id = 1  WHERE product_id = ".$id;
                $connection->query($sql);
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: in custom table ???

Comment: In upgrade schema of 'cataloginventory_stock_item' table

Comment: I want to save a custom field in 'cataloginventory_stock_item'  table https://prnt.sc/nm0ce5

Comment: Hi @divyasekar have you saved the fields into that table? I am also facing similar issue..Could you update the answer

Comment: Hi @aravind i was updated my post

Comment: Thankyou @divyasekar, but it automatically get's saved  into db if through product_form itself..No need to add event/plugin to save those fields..

Comment: @aravind I am not clear on your comments, could you please explained ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

> Cm/Preorder/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="preorder_button" instance="Cm\Preorder\Observer\AfterProductSave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Cm\Preorder\Observer\AfterProductSave.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\Preorder\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class AfterProductSave implements ObserverInterface
{ 
     protected $_scopeConfig;
     protected $_request;
     protected $_objectManager;


     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager


    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_request = $request;

    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

         $_product = $observer->getProduct();  // you will get product object 
        $product_id = $_product->getId();
        $preorder_button=$_product->getPreorderButton(); 
        $preorder_note=$_product->getPreorderNote();

        $display_text= $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('preorder/display/btn_text');
         $display_note= $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('preorder/display/pre_order_note');


            $preorder_button = $display_text;        


            $preorder_note = $display_note;

        $resource = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` WHERE  `product_id`=$product_id";
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
         $res = $connection->fetchAll($query);
        if($res)
            {
               $var = array_column($res, 'product_id');
                $key = key($var);
                $id = $var[$key];
                $sql = "UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` SET preorder_button = '$preorder_button' , preorder_note ='$preorder_note' , website_id = 1  WHERE product_id = ".$id;
                $connection->query($sql);
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: Hello @divya I can able to save in table, but after save it's not automatically populated on the custom field, how to populate the saved value in that field

Comment: Thanks @divya, pls share it to kknsenthil@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

**created Observer which calls Cataloginventory Stock Item Save After event.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after">
        <observer name="Vendor_Module::save_custom_data" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AfterProductSave"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**And In Your AfterProductSave.php file You Can Add Your Custom 
Field Value**

Comment: I will try and update you

Comment: working or not ??

Comment: no, its not working

Comment: any error or  issue ???????

Comment: not yet  but custom field values not saved in db

Comment: event called or not

Comment: I called a event, but  its not possible

Comment: i would not get a posted values

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to implement [extension attribute](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) for `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface`.

Use these two fields as [extension_attributes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) on  `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for=Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface">
        <attribute code="preorder_button" type="string" />
        <attribute code="preorder_note" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

### Save on using Plugin

Then  create plugin on `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockItemRepositoryInterface:save`

and this attribute value.

Like below

```
<?php
namespace {YourNamespace};

class SaveDataPlugin {

    public function beforeSave
    (
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockItemRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface $stockItem
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $subject->getExtensionAttributes();
        if (
                null !== $extensionAttributes &&
                null !== $extensionAttributes->getPreorderButton()
        ) {
            $Value = $extensionAttributes->getPreorderButton()->getValue();
            $stockItem->setPreorderButton($Value);
        }
        if (null !== $extensionAttributes &&
            null !== $extensionAttributes->getPreorderNote()
        ) {
            $Value = $extensionAttributes->getPreorderNote()->getValue();
            $stockItem->setPreorderNote($Value);
        }        
        return $stockItem;
    }

}
```

### Note that code is posted base on Idea, not Test